# load xgboost model generated in sagemaker

Tags: python, xgboost

I used to be able to load a tared sagemaker model like so:

```
local_model_path = "model.tar.gz"
with tarfile.open(local_model_path) as tar:
    tar.extractall()

model = xgb.XGBRegressor() 
model.load_model('xgboost-model')
```

when I try to do this now with a later version of xgboost (in Sagemaker) I believe I get:

```
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 736, in load_model
    self.get_booster().load_model(fname)
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 2249, in load_model
    _check_call(_LIB.XGBoosterLoadModel(
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 203, in _check_call
    raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: string too long
```

What could be the reason for this please?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this one out?  I'm having the same issue (though my .model file was generated in R).

Comment: not sure if I can help with R. IIRC there are different storage encoding though so it should/could be language agnostic. I think in the end I used an older image to train the model in sagemaker: estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(image_uri=sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve("xgboost", region_name, "1.5-1") later images store the models in a different format and the above code did not work ...